# How can I enable WYSIWYG for product attribute field?

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

I want to enable the WYSIWYG editor on a custom product atribute. It displays on description and short description however not on the custom product attribute.

[image: No WYSIWYG for custom attribute]

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In "Product Attribute" page, when you choose "text area", go down to "Frontend Properties" and Enable "Enable WYSIWYG"

Comment: Didn't think it would be in frontend! Thanks very much

Comment: Where is the "Product Attribute" page?